# How to catch an error before it happens? fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

I'm new to this so bear with me please.  I have a Master-Detail app and am having issues when running the app in Portrait iPad.  Master shows a table view, that when cell is clicked on, an image shows up on the Detail page.  It's crashing on the imageView1.image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage!  Note that this works in iPhone.  I think what's happening is because the flowerImage has not yet loaded so there is no value.  By the way, the error is: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     imageView1.image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage!
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    configureView()
}
```

Code for SplitViewController:

```
import UIKit
```

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController,
UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.delegate = self
    self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
}

func splitViewController(
    _ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
    collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
    onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // Return true to prevent UIKit from applying its default behavior
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: do a guard on your image, so that if it's nil you'll know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're not sure that the object can't be nil, then don't use force unwrapping.

You can use several options:
1. "guard let" statement:

```
guard let image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage else{
    //add some notification about error here
    return
}
imageView1.image = image
```

2. "if let" statement

   if let image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage {
           imageView1.image = image
   }else {
        //add some notification about error here
   }